# "Old" Software slower on Windows 10?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10

in our company we still have a "dinosaur" when it comes down to software: Word 95

It is running fine with Windows 10 (64bit), but can't be replaced easily, cause it has been stuffed
with Macros for 25 Years now.

Word 95 only runs on one core, hence all the modern 12-20 core cpus don't offer anything.

But we noted, that - on two equal hardware-configurations - The very same "job" is significantly slower on Windows 10 than it used to be on Windows 7. (30s vs. 5 Minutes)

It's a macro generating documents, reading various other documents, putting them together, doing lookups in txt/csv files etc...

Do you have any Idea what might cause this difference in performance?
All Major applications generally run faster with Windows 10, compared to Windows 7.

Comment: Word macros are not backward compatible? Even if not, somebody ought to be able to migrate those relatively easily.

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's about Macros from Word95. That was a time, where a common basis was unknown. They are not even "vba", they are "vb-word95", not even working in the same yeaers Exce... ähm... Microsoft Works... totally hardcoded macro language, where even the Method-Calls are localized and not work in the same app, when using another ui-language...

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of emulation and backward compatibility tricks are done by the OS to get such an ancient application to even run at all on Windows 10 x64; that would be more than enough to slow it down to a crawl.

Comment: I have the feeling, it's mainly caused by file-access. Every macro not accessing files is running about equal fast (as fast a single-core-app can go)